# How to multiply two columns in a table together to produce a new column

Tags: html-table, rows

I have 2 fields quantity and price. I basically want to multiply them together and get a value for another column called Price (Which is the total of the multiplication).

I have tried using the below html code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_order_quantity*item.ITEM.item_price)
```

This is my Table row code:

```
           <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> Item Description</th>
                        <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> Quantity</th>
                        <th><i class="icon_calendar"></i> Price</th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.ITEM_ORDER)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEM.item_description)
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_order_quantity)
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_order_quantity*item.ITEM.item_price)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", new { id = item.OrderID }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.OrderID }) |

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.OrderID })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider having an additional property in your `viewmodel` or `Model` which does this task for you. Then you can bind this with html helper as you did for every other field.

```
public class YourViewModel
    {
        public int Field1{ get; set; }
        public int Field2{ get; set; }
        public int CalculatedField{ 
                  get {return Field1*Field2;}
            }
    }
```

Or try below code which calculates the value and stores in variable, then renders value directly from variable.

try this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> Item Description</th>
                        <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> Quantity</th>
                        <th><i class="icon_calendar"></i> Price</th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.ITEM_ORDER)
                    {
                       var computedValue = item.item_order_quantity*item.ITEM.item_price
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEM.item_description)
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_order_quantity)
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @(computedValue)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", new { id = item.OrderID }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.OrderID }) |

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.OrderID })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked like a charm. What I need to do now is constantly have a over all total for the customer invoice at the bottom and add VAT to this and maybe count the number of items as well. How would i do this? Would it be in the table?